# Try to change files name in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying my first program in BASH
The program needs to change the files name in directory.
The first argument is base name and the second argument is a file extension
If I call to the function with:

```
  rename Test jpg
```

then the resulting files should have names like:

```
  Test001.jpg, Test002.jpg, Test003.jpg,...
```

What I tried:

```
     function rename {
     index=0
     for i in $1"/"*".$2"; do
     newName=$(printf $1/"$1%04d."$2 ${index})
     mv $i $newName
     let index=index+1
     done
     }
```

And when I call to the function

```
  bash rename.sh pwd jpg
```

And nothing dosen't happened,please help me:)

Comment: where you calling your function???

Comment: bash rename.sh pwd jpg

Comment: Does your original script contain anything other than a `function` definition? You need to have some commands outside a function for the shell to do anything useful with the script.

Comment: You don't increment your `index`

Comment: I have to add that I will delete my answer below because I think that your problem is not well posed.  What do you think will happen if in the `Test` directory you have some files named `Test/Testxxxx.jpg`? Imho you are going to risk data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do :

```
rn(){
     for i in $1*.$2; do
     ((index++))
     newName=$(printf "$1%04d.$2" $index)
     mv $i $newName
     done
}

cd WHERE/YOU/WANT    
rn "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks,And how I call a function to work on the current folder?

Comment: And I got error: mv: cannot stat ‘/home/user/Desktop/testRename/*.img’: No such file or directory

Comment: Removed the test `echo` command from the script. Tested OK for me, bash 4.3.11

Comment: last thing..why the name isn't include the directory name? the new name is only 0001.jpg,0002.jpg and not Directory001.jpg etc..